# Tooltip no comentário sobre edição sugerida

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Na tela "Analisar -> Edição Sugerida", ao passar o mouse sobre o comentário deixado pelo autor da edição, o tooltip lê:

> comentar sobre esta edição sugerida

Não deveria ser "comentar" (verbo), e sim "comentário" (substantivo):

> comentário sobre esta edição sugerida